# Modify file permissions using C API

Tags: c, linux, ioctl

I have a server component that reads its configuration from a file. The configuration file is also read and written by an administration component. The components are separate programs, and they will be running under separate accounts. I want to change the ACL on the configuration file to:

```
application: read
administration: read and write
```

Its important to drop write from the application because the application opens a listening socket. That is, its high risk and I want to contain it as much as possible.

After some searching, it looks like `ioctl` is used to do it in C. `ioctl_list` offers a list of control codes but its not apparent to me how to add two users with different permissions on the configuration file. The man page online at [die.net](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ioctl_list) does not discuss the permissions in-depth or offer sample code. For example the word "perm" (root of "permission") only shows up once in the discussion.

On Windows, reducing permission to honor least privilege is drawn out but its pretty straight forward (Richter gives good examples in his [Advanced Windows](http://www.amazon.com/Jeffrey-Richter/e/B000APH134) programming series).

How does one change permissions on a linux file using C APIs? What control codes are to be used?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `man 2 chmod` BTW: I don't understand the problem with the listen socket. BTW2: this is elementary UNIX stuff, not even advanced. Maybe you should do some reading first.

Comment: ACL's use the acl API set in linux.  See p. 330 - in 'The Linux Programming Interface' M Kerrisk.  This page has code with the API calls hyperlinked to explanations. [Linux ACL](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/dist/acl/acl_update.c.html)

Comment: Thanks wildplasser. I'm not sure what you don't understand, sorry. By the way, `chmod` only takes a path and a mode, not a user/group for the advanced attributes (and yes, I looked at `chattr`).

Comment: Thanks Jim. "The Linux Programming Interface" - awesome, I have that book. Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not done with `ioctl`, but rather with dedicated system calls: [`chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chmod), [`chown`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chown), and [`chgrp`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chgrp) for the basic user/group/other set of file permissions, and [`acl_*`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/acl) for full-fledged ACLs.  You probably also want to know about the [`setuid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setuid), [`setgid`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setgid), and [`setgroups`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setgroups) system calls, which are how you drop privileges in a running application.

You can accomplish your goals using only the basic user/group/other permissions.  Configure your system as follows:

- The server application has a dedicated user ID and group; let's say they are both named `nlserver` ("nl" for "noloader").
- The administrative component also has a dedicated user ID and group, let's say `nladmin`.
- The configuration file is set to be mode 0640 (aka `-rw-r-----`) and owned by user `nladmin`, group `nlserver`.  (The code responsible for doing this should be in the administrative component, not the server itself.)
- When the server starts up, after doing everything it needs to do as `root` (e.g. bind low-numbered ports), it uses `setgroups`, `setgid`, and `setuid` (IN THAT ORDER!) to change to user `nlserver`, group `nlserver`, and clear the supplementary groups list.  Only after doing so does it open the configuration file.

Comment: Thanks Zack. I never realized that's why groups and users are mixed and matched. I think I can avoid `acl_*` APIs altogether. So I'm clear: if a third user/group needed special access, then I would need to use `acl_*` Is that correct?

Comment: If there are other processes that need to *read* the file you can just add them to the `nlserver` group (processes can be in lots of groups at once, this is the point of `setgroups` and `getgroups`).  But if something else needs to *write* the file, and it is inappropriate for it to run as either the `nladmin` or `root` user, then yes, you need ACLs.